# Is there a closed form solution for modular equations of this form?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

For background (which is not needed to answer the question), this question came up in my attempt to solve this [code golf problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/224876/generate-the-ticks-of-a-graph).

Given known constants $A$, $B$, and $C$, is there a closed form solution that gives a minimal positive integer $x$ satisfying the following equation?

$$C \leq\frac{(A \bmod x) + B}x < C+1$$

If so, what is that solution?

For clarity, here is a [WolframAlpha link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4+%3C%3D+%28%28%2817+mod+x%29+%2B+39%29%2Fx%29+%3C+5) correctly finding the answer 10 when $A = 17$, $B = 39$, and $C=4$.  However, WolframAlpha doesn't indicate the method it uses to find the answer, so it might be exhaustive search.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha missed that $11$ is another solution,.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for the formatting edit.  I see 11 listed under 10 on WolframAlpha.  Also, for clarity, for my question, only 10 is valid since it must be minimal, but I couldn't figure out how to specify that on WA.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all are positive, you need $C-1<\frac Bx<C+1.$ or $$\frac B{C+1}<x<\frac B{C-1}.$$

After that, probably the best you can do is trial and error. There will be about $$\left\lfloor\frac{2B}{C^2-1}\right\rfloor$$ values to try.

$A=17, B=39,C=4$ means you need: $\frac{39}5<x<\frac{39}3$ or $8\leq x\leq 12.$

Both $10$ and $11$ are solutions.

---

Rewriting $A\bmod x=A-x\lfloor A/x\rfloor$ this rewrites your equation as:

$$\left\lfloor\frac{A+B}x\right\rfloor- \left\lfloor\frac{A}x\right\rfloor=C$$

I’m not sure how useful that is.